# How do I create a curved, circular, or swerving travel path for an object across a flat plane surface?

Tags: animation

Please direct me to the relevant program elements of Blender that I will need to establish a turning and swerving X-Y travel path for a single symmetrical object on a flat plane surface.
Also, I would additionally like to have an attached linear object swinging and/or tugging more vertically away and in the direction of motion of the main symmetrical object, much like a leash movement from a dog on a walk.

Thanks,
Don Burke

Comment: For the first part, look for tutorials on Curves and the Follow Path constraint. There are several quick YT tutorials online showing you how to set it up.

Comment: Hello Donald, and welcome. The curved motion of the 'dog' could be, as @John Eason says, a _Follow Path_ constraint, or just key-framing locations and rotations.. the imitation or simulation of the leash is really another question, Maybe it would be worth re-framing this question, if appropriate, as something more like: ' How would I simulate the tugging on a dog-leash?' .. or whatever it is you actually want to wind up with.